# Filter is not working

Tags: apache-pig, biginsights

We are trying to filter the hdfs data using Pig query.We have data enclosed within double quotes.Eg: "AAA","BBB","YYY".In which we are trying to filter YYY
We tried the following ways of filter,

```
FILTER a BY XXX == 'YYY';
FILTER a BY XXX == '.*YYY.*';
FILTER a BY XXX == '\'\YYY\"\';
```

Looking forward for your help to go head.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to use regular expressions. In that case, you have a few problems. You need to use `MATCHES` rather than `==`, you have to match the entire string, not just a substring, and when using metacharacters, you have to escape the backslash, as with any Java string: `\\d` to match a digit, not `\d`.